# How to assign values to JSON object

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that does not work.  I am trying to push the text "John" onto the end of the object.  I am more familiar with PHP, and this works in PHP.

```
var data = {};
var field_name = "first_name";

data[field_name]['answers'][] = "John";

alert(data['first_name']['answers'][0]);
```

**Edit:**

I also tried the following and it did not work.

```
var data = {};
var field_name = "first_name";
var i=0;

data[field_name]['answers'][i] = "John";

alert(data['first_name']['answers'][0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var data = {};
var field_name = "first_name";
data[field_name] = {};
data[field_name].answers = [];
data[field_name].answers.push("John");

alert(data['first_name'].answers[0]);
```

Comment: That's not working for some reason.  I tested your code exactly as it is written.

Comment: Added another line please retry

Comment: answers need to be in an object first: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EVsM2/

var dataObj = {
    "first_name":{
        "answers":["John"]
    }
  }

Comment: It works.  Thanks.  What if I wanted to assign the value using JSON instead of a Javascript array (like in the second example I gave above)?  Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks mplungjan. I think I understand.

Comment: The answer below touches on it .. but essentially you cannot as a JS array has bounds that you must assign within or use push / pop to add and remove from

Answer (score 0):

One can't arbitrarily define more array dimensions or dynamically extend bounds like PHP will happily allow. You'll need to do something like this (the shorthand [ ] notation can also be used in place of new Array(). I just prefer this way.):

```
var data = {};
var field_name = "first_name";

//Create the new dimensions
data[field_name] = new Array();
data[field_name]['answers'] = new Array();
//Push the new element
data[field_name]['answers'].push("John");

alert(data['first_name']['answers'][0]);​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: var data = new Array() should be var data = {} and data[field_name] = new Array();
 should be data[field_name] = {} and 
data[field_name]['answers'] = new Array();
should be data[field_name]['answers'] = [];